# Does my site need to pop up a cookie prompt ie. "We use cookies and you have to accept them..."?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

This is probably a silly question but I have to ask it.

A lot of sites pop up a "We use cookies and you have to accept them etc...". I am making a Node/React/Express app which uses a basic login and nothing else notable (maybe will use payments too in the future).

According to an EU law, that's necessary if your site uses cookies. Now I am not using cookies for anything explicitly, so is it a must for me to use the pop up aswell?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a popup. If you're operating in the EU, it appears as though you should have a banner or something informing the user that there will be cookies used.

It actually looks like the EU has a little script you can put on your page that will automatically provide the banner. See the link below for more.

http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm

Comment: Yea that's probably what I wanted to ask: do I have to use this banner no matter what?

Comment: Read the source I sent. It outlines certain types of cookies which are exempt. If you’re only using cookies for those reasons it doesn’t appear like you need anything.